# Android browser downloading images automatically

Tags: android, html

When I visit my site from android (Froyo 2.2) browser and when i click to view image it start to automatically download that image instead of displaying the image in browser.
How can I display my images in browser instead of downloading them?

My browser is set up to load images in settings and I can view pictures on other sites without downloading them to my sd card or phone memory.

Thanks!

Comment: i will wonder if it is a developers question but notnormal mobile users query . better if you will put app technical details like code snippet and other environment details

Comment: I'm not making an application, I think it's more html issue on my site but it's also about android. That's why I posted in both android and html sections of stackoverflow.

For example I can view http://i.imgur.com/W0hBC.jpg in my browser but when I visit picture on my site like http://img2go.com/i/4e876199c8dcf.jpg it start to download image automatically

Answer (score 1):

If your site when you click on the image send you directly to the image file then that's probably why the android browser tries to download it since he understands it as file. Maybe you should try to display the image in an html file.

For example when you click on an image, it could direct you to an html file with a parameter of the image name. Then inside that html you can have a javascript code that will load and display that image.